# T-SQL Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

This is my  query.
I want to run query but I could not run.
Please help me.

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols += N'' + QUOTENAME(Kriter) + ', '
FROM   (
        SELECT DISTINCT Kriter
        FROM NetBarakatMalzemeAnalizFormu where MalzemeKodu = 'DEM2020'                         
        ) a                         
SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)
SET @sql    = N'SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    Deger,
    BalyaId,
    Kriter
  FROM NetBarakatMalzemeAnalizFormu where MalzemeKodu = ''DEM2020''
) StudentResults
PIVOT (
  SUM([Deger])
  FOR [Kriter]
  IN
   (' + @cols + ')
  
) AS PivotTable'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

And this is error screen

Thank you.

Comment: This would occur if there `@cols` were an empty string.  Your "bug" is really a symptom of another problem.

Comment: A nice debug step is to print ```@cols``` before you perform your substring so you can see what it looks like prior to the error being generated. I suspect Gordon is correct; if @cols is empty, you’ll get a substring error.

Comment: I, personally, prefer `STUFF` to remove the leading character over `LEFT` to remove a trailing one; it would avoid the error in this case too (though not the underlying issue).

Comment: "And this is error screen"? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score -1):

As Gordon said, the error is due to `@Cols` having an empty value. This stems from the fact that your subquery is returning no rows.

Personally, however, I recommend changing to `STUFF` to remove the **leading** character (not the trailing) and using a method other than the (can be) unreliable method of `@variable += @Variable`. Considering you're on SQL server 2017 then you really should be using `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
DECLARE @Cols nvarchar(MAX), --Notice no default value
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SELECT @Cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Kriter),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Kriter)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Kriter
      FROM NetBarakatMalzemeAnalizFormu 
      WHERE MalzemeKodu = 'DEM2020') NBMAF;

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    Deger,
    BalyaId,
    Kriter
  FROM NetBarakatMalzemeAnalizFormu where MalzemeKodu = ''DEM2020''
) StudentResults
PIVOT (
  SUM([Deger])
  FOR [Kriter]
  IN
   (' + STUFF(@cols,1,1,N'') + N')
  
) AS PivotTable;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

This won't run anything, based on your error, however, won't error. It will, however, work correctly when a dataset is returned.